# Is it possible to add a banner to a forwarded Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I have a few infrequently used Gmail accounts which forward on to another account which is regularly monitored.

When these infrequently used accounts receive emails and forward them on, I can get very similar looking emails which actually come from different addresses yet look at a very quick glance to be duplicates which is mildly annoying.

Is there any easy way to add a banner or prefix the subject line for example to say "this originated from..." or something along those lines?

I know there are banners which are added to emails identifying that the email originated outside a domain or a warning about containing viruses etc. but I'm guessing this is a feature of the local server so was wondering whether there was anything that could be done with Gmail.

Comment: Have you tried the given solutions? Did any work for you? If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well. If not, please let us know.

Comment: @marikamitsos I quite like your 2nd option however the template gets forwarded on so I get the template contents (custom banner text) but not the contents of the original email. Have I missed something here or is this deliberate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is.

#### Using labels in your monitoring/master account

**Steps**:

1. Go to `Settings -->Filters` and create a new filter by adding the email in the `To` field.

[image]

2. Create a new label for the accounts like: `email01`

[image]

3. Repeat above steps for any number of email accounts.

*The downside is that when emails are sent to a list you have no recipient.*

Comment: I quite like your 2nd option however the template gets forwarded on so I get the template contents (custom banner text) but not the contents of the original email.  
Have I missed something here or is this deliberate?

Comment: I am afraid you are not missing anything. **I was**. I had used the second option a very long time ago. But that was as an auto reply. So I got confused and didn't double check it. Sorry about that. I has now been withdrawn from my answer. On the bright side, I still do use the first option extremely successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter based on the to: field and choosing to apply a label as the action.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136046)

Comment: Why not? The label can be interpreted as a textual banner. By the way, there is another answer which offers the same suggestion and got a vote; the only difference from mine is that its author made some sceenshots.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: So what? Wasn't I polite? This is for you: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."